# Call to undifined method

Tags: php

I have quite the situation here, my code complies with no problems what so ever in dev environment but when I deploy it to production something goes south and tells me that the class' method is not defined. Checked on production, the code is there PHP versions are identical to the one we are using on development.

Error message: Call to undefined method Action\Supplier\Shipment\ShipmentController::getOverview()

Class definiation:

```
namespace Action\Supplier\Shipment;


class ShipmentController extends Controller
{

    protected $service;

    public function __construct(OrderServiceInterface $service)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->service = $service;
    }

    //Other methods defined, they are properly terminated.

    public function getOverview() {
        //logic
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
class Controller
{
    protected $templates;

    protected $databaseConnection;

    protected $logged;

    /**
     * Controller constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->templates = new Engine();
        $this->templates->loadExtension();
    }

    public function getTemplates()
    {
        return $this->templates;
    }

    public function setTemplates($templates)
    {
        $this->templates = $templates;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDatabaseConnection()
    {
        return $this->databaseConnection;
    }

    public function setDatabaseConnection($databaseConnection)
    {
        $this->databaseConnection = $databaseConnection;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getLogged()
    {
        return $this->logged;
    }

    public function setLogged()
    {
    }

    protected function setHttpStatus()
    {
    }
}
```

Usage of class:

```
use Action\Supplier\Shipment\ShipmentController;


$service    = new IrreleventClass();
$controller = new ShipmentController($service);
$controller->getOverview();
```

Edit: Answer in the comments.

Comment: Share your `Controller` class code

Comment: Restart your webserver service like apache and php-fpm. This will clean the OP caches.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Just figured out a few minutes ago that it was indeed a caching issue, thank you!